# Configure Nginx behind AWS ALB for Jira

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, nginx, jira, amazon-elb

I've got a requirement that We have Jira application on EC2 instance which is behind AWS ALB. We are offloading SSL and redirecting http to https in ALB itself.

We want to install Nginx as a reverse proxy for application to gain some performance benefits still having ALB in place.

So the request goes like this

Client -> AWS ELB -> Nginx -> (Apache)Jira

I've configured Nginx to route requests from ALB to Jira. But that application URLs are not forming correctly.

Can anyone help me out how should I configure this?

```
server {
        listen       8888;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {

              # redirecting jira
                proxy_pass      http://localhost:8080;
        }
}
```

Comment: where is your nginx settings?

Comment: Nginx settings in the same server where Jira runs. i.e EC2

Comment: I mean can I see?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: You can redirect the port from ALB then why you need the proxy from nginx? Simply get the request from 8888 and send those traffic into the jira target group with port 8080. I won't get any performance benefit from this.

Comment: Agreed with @Lamanus, if you're not using Nginx as a balancer or adding HTTP headers, or caching, or any other than a proxy, then it's not necessary. Just add a rule in ALB to pass any 8888 to backend:8080 and that's it.